# Call WCF method on Windows Shutdown sometimes fails

Tags: windows, wcf, call, shutdown

I have a WPF Application that on Windows Shutdown (System.Windows.Application.Current.SessionEnding event) calls a WCF method asynchronously and then the application is closed. But sometimes the WCF method never reaches the server side.

I have logs on both client and server side that tells me when the request is made and completed. Most of the times it works well, i can see the client's request reaching the server and then the application exits. But sometimes i can only see the client making the request and never reaching the server.

I think the issue could be that in the process of windows shutting down, sometimes the WCF request from my WPF application is made when the network connection is already off. Could this be the reason? If it is, is there some workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Can you wait closing your application until your Completed event handler is is called back by the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you're making the call Asyncronously then it's happening on a background thread.

Background threads cannot stop the application closing and are terminated when the app closes.  What may be happening is that the OS tells your app that it's shutting down the PC, your app tries to make its Async request but doesn't manage to do so because the background thread that is making it is killed as the app shuts down.  This won't necessarily happen all the time but will definitely happen because there's nothing there to ensure that the thread is kept alive.

What you should do is explicitly create a new thread and use this to call your service syncronously.  By manually creating a thread you can set it to be a foreground thread; foreground threads won't allow an app to shutdown until they're completed. so:

```
public void OnShutdown()
{
    var executionThread=new Thread(RunWcfMethod);
    executionThread.IsBackgroundThread=false;
    executionThread.Start();
}

private void RunWcfMethod()
{
    var serviceClient=new ShutdownServiceClient();
    serviceClient.NotifyServerOfShutdownSyncronously();
}
```